# What configs influence whether user credentials/grants are written to the binlog in Mysql

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.5

I have a fairly trivial master-master setup.
When testing this setup I see that mysql users are binlogged and replicated on slaves. However on each of the masters the binlog-do-db* is for a specific database only:

```
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
| File             | Position | Binlog_Do_DB | Binlog_Ignore_DB |
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
| mysql-bin.000001 |      694 | my_db        |                  |
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
```

Why are DDL queries like (CREATE USER) **and** inserts into `mysql.user` logged as well? I can't see any mechanisms/configs in the manual which explain this, seemingly, exception.

If it matters, the binlog format is:

```
mysql> show variables like 'binlog_format';
+---------------+-----------+
| Variable_name | Value     |
+---------------+-----------+
| binlog_format | STATEMENT |
+---------------+-----------+
```

* = Let's forget about the bad-practice of using binlog-do-db for now

Comment: No, let's not.  The `USER` info is in the database `mysql`.

Comment: Okay, so why are these mysql-database changes included in the binlog?

Answer (score -1):

You are replicating *only* `my_db`.

There are valid security reasons for having the option to not replicate `mysql`.

The quick solution is to add `binlog_do_db=mysql` and restart.  However, any `GRANTs` and `CREATE USERs` have already been lost.  Either re-issue them and hope they replicate, or replay them on the Slave(s).

Comment: But that's the thing.. It *is* replicating the mysql-db. See my second paragraph

Comment: Sorry, I misread.  What version are you running?  (I wonder if this has changed over the years.)